# HTML signature leaves big spaces between rows (Gmail App from Outlook)

Tags: outlook, gmail, html-email

This is how it looks in GMail mobile app when sent from Outlook:

[image]

How can I avoid those big gaps?

My code is as follows:

```
<table id="sig" width='320' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border-spacing='0' style="width:320px;margin:0;padding:0;">
    <tr>
        <td valign='top' width="120" height="48" style="width:120px;height:48px;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;">
            <a style="border:none;text-decoration:none;">
          <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media_crisalix/signatures/logo.jpg" alt="Crisalix" width='120' height='48' style="border:none;width:120px;height:48px;display:block;">
      </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="sig1" cellspacing='0' width='320' cellpadding='0' border-spacing='0' style="padding:0;margin:0;font-family:sans-serif,Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:11px;color:#b0b0b0;border-collapse:collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;width:320px;">
        <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
          <td style="width:320px;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:sans-serif,Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;white-space:nowrap;font-weight:600;line-height:1.6;font-size:13px;">
            <span style="color:#137191">Jaime</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
          <td style="width:320px;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:sans-serif,Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;white-space:nowrap;font-size:12px;line-height:1">
            <span style="color:#555555">Chief Executive Officer</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign='top' width="27" height='21' style="width:27px;height:1px;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;">
            <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media_crisalix/signatures/separator.jpg" alt="Crisalix" width='27' height='21' style="border:none;width:27px;height:21px;display:block;">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
          <td style="width:320px;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:sans-serif,Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;white-space:nowrap;font-size:12px;line-height:1.4;">
            <div><span style="color:#137191;font-weight:bold">P / </span><span style="color:#555555;"></span></div>
            <div><span style="color:#137191;font-weight:bold">A / </span><span style="color:#555555">Parc Scientifique (PSE-A) - EPFL1015</span></div>
            <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#555555"> Lausanne | Switzerland </span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
          <td style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:sans-serif,Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;white-space:nowrap;font-weight:600;line-height:1.6;font-size:13px;width:320px;">
            <a href="http://www.crisalix.com" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#137191;"><span style="color:#137191;border:none;text-decoration:none!important;color:#137191;">www.crisalix.com</span></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign='top' width="27" height='21' style="width:27px;height:1px;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;">
            <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media_crisalix/signatures/separator.jpg" alt="Crisalix" width='27' height='21' style="border:none;width:27px;height:21px;display:block;">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </td>
    </table>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign='top' width="230" height="225" style="width:230px;height:225px;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;">
      <a href='http://www.crisalix.com' title="Crisalix" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;">
        <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media_crisalix/signatures/signature-banner.jpg" alt="Crisalix" width='230' height='225' style="border:none;width:230px;height:225px;display:block;">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding 'line-height: 1 !important' to the text?