# spaces between images outlook HTML

Tags: html, outlook, gmail, html-email

When sending this HTML signature in outlook, it shows space between images. Each image as "display:block" so I'm not sure what the problem could be. This is what it shows when sending from outlook to the mobile gmail app.

[image]

```
<body>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<style type='text/css'>
  a.link{margin:0;padding:0;border:none !important;text-decoration:none !important;}
  table,tr,td,a,span{font-family:sans-serif,Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;}
</style>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
<meta name='format-detection' content='telephone=no' />
<meta name='format-detection' content='address=no' />
<meta name='format-detection' content='email=no' />

<table id="sig" border='0' width='320' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border-spacing='0' style="width:320px;margin:0;padding:0;">
    <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
        <td valign='top' width="120" height="48" style="width:120px;height:48px;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;line-height:1!important;">
            <a href='http://www.crisalix.com' title="Crisalix" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;display:block;line-height:1!important;">
          <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media_crisalix/signatures/logo.jpg" alt="Crisalix" width='120' height='48' style="border:none;width:120px;height:48px;display:block;">
      </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <td style="width:320px;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:sans-serif,Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;white-space:nowrap;line-height:1!important;">
      <span style="color:#137191;line-height:21px!important;font-size:13px;display:inline-block;;font-weight:600;">, PhD</span><br>
      <span style="color:#555555;line-height:18px!important;font-size:13px;display:inline-block;">Chief Executive Officer</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <td valign='top' width="27" height='21' style="width:27px;height:1px;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;line-height:1!important;">
      <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media_crisalix/signatures/separator.jpg" alt="Crisalix" width='27' height='21' style="border:none;width:27px;height:21px;display:block;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <td style="width:320px;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:sans-serif,Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;white-space:nowrap;font-size:12px;line-height:1!important;">
      <span style="color:#137191;font-weight:bold;display:inline-block;line-height:21px!important;display:inline-block;line-height:21px">P / </span><span style="color:#555555;display:inline-block;line-height:21px!important;">&nbsp;+41 78 720 2521 | +34 633 441 648</span><br>
      <span style="color:#137191;font-weight:bold;line-height:21px!important;display:inline-block;">A / </span><span style="color:#555555;display:inline-block;line-height:21px!important;"> &nbsp;Parc Scientifique (PSE-A) - EPFL1015</span><br>
      <span style="color:#555555;display:inline-block;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lausanne | Switzerland </span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <td style="margin:0;padding:0;font-family:sans-serif,Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica;white-space:nowrap;font-weight:600;line-height:1!important;font-size:13px;width:320px;">
      <a href="http://www.crisalix.com" style="border:none!important;text-decoration:none!important;color:#137191;display:block;line-height:24px!important;"><span style="color:#137191;border:none;text-decoration:none!important;color:#137191;display:block;line-height:24px!important;">www.crisalix.com</span></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <td valign='top' width="27" height='21' style="width:27px;height:1px;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;line-height:1!important;">
      <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media_crisalix/signatures/separator.jpg" alt="Crisalix" width='27' height='21' style="border:none;width:27px;height:21px;display:block;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <td valign='top' width="230" height="225" style="width:230px;height:225px;margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:top;line-height:1!important;">
      <a href='http://www.crisalix.com' title="Crisalix" style="border:none;text-decoration:none;">
        <img moz-do-not-send="true" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media_crisalix/signatures/signature-banner.jpg" alt="Crisalix" width='230' height='225' style="border:none;width:230px;height:225px;display:block;">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
&nbsp;
</body>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you paste this HTML? I do have Outlook.com account, but it does not let me paste HTML, only edit it inline. I'm wondering do I have to set up desktop Outlook to test this. cheers =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML signature leaves big spaces between rows (Gmail App from Outlook)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212423/html-signature-leaves-big-spaces-between-rows-gmail-app-from-outlook)